# Issue in running mapreduce program

Tags: mapreduce

i am trying to write a custome word count program.but i am getting an error saying "Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable" where as u can see i have not used LongWritable anywhere in the program. please guide to resolve this issue and correct where i went wrong.

Program:
public class customeWordCount {

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<Text, IntWritable, Text,IntWritable>{
    private static IntWritable count;
    private static Text wordCropped;
    public void map(IntWritable key, Text value,
            Context context)
            throws IOException,InterruptedException {
    TreeMap map = new TreeMap(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);


        String word = null;
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word =tokenizer.nextToken();

        if(word.length()>=3){
             wordCropped.set(word.substring(0, 3));

            if(map.containsKey( wordCropped.toString().toLowerCase())){
                count = (IntWritable) map.get(wordCropped);


                context.write(wordCropped, (IntWritable)count);

            }
            else {
                context.write(wordCropped, (IntWritable)count);
            }
        }
            }


    }

}
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>{

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context)
            throws IOException,InterruptedException {
        int sum=0;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(IntWritable x: values)
        {
            sum++;

        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //JobConf conf = new JobConf(Al.class);
    Configuration conf= new Configuration();


    //conf.setJobName("mywc");
    Job job = new Job(conf,"Custome_count");

    job.setJarByClass(customeWordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    //conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    //conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);

    //Defining the output value class for the mapper

    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);



    Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

        //Configuring the input/output path from the filesystem into the job

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        //deleting the output path automatically from hdfs so that we don't have delete it explicitly

    outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath);

        //exiting the job only if the flag value becomes false

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

}

Comment: i feel like there is some issue in main class.. 
i tried changing job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class); to job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); similar change in job.setMapInputValueClass(IntWritable.class); to job.setMapInputValueClass(Text.class); but i am getting error saying "Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
"

any expert to help me here. thanks in advance :)

Comment: request someone to help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have text files as input, the InputFormat that will be used is [TextInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html). This format has LongWritable as key and Text as value.

Having said that, your mapper should be declared as:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text,IntWritable>
```

and your map method signature must change to:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException,InterruptedException
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. I will incorporate your inputs and get back ... :)